# Delete Entire page of Word Document using office js

Tags: ms-word, office-js, office-addins, word-addins, word-web-addins

I want to delete the entire page where the current cursor is, and the page can contain tables, images, and other content. The code I have provided works when the page has no data or only text data. However, if I try to delete a page from a table or any other section, this code fails.

```js
export async function deletePage() {

  return Word.run(async (context) => {
    let range = context.document.getSelection();
    let pageRange = range.parentBody.getRange();

    pageRange.delete();

    await context.sync();

  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
    if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
      console.log("Debug info: " + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
    }
  });

}
```

Comment: You need to say more than "this code fails". What exactly goes wrong. What do you expect to see and what do you actually see. Can you provide a screenshot of the document? Also, can you reproduce the problem in the Script Lab tool? ?

Answer (score 0):

So you have to clear the non-plain text objects before deleting the plain text. (ie. the line:)

```
pageRange.delete();
```

I don't know js, I'll show you the operation with VBA, you can find the corresponding objects and methods in the js file to try it out.

I have tested, if your **getRange** is well written, like my **GetPageRange** function here,can get the correct page range in a document, not just the text range in it, then the execution of *"pageRange.Delete"* will be error-free. In the page after adding the chart and table, I use my VBA to clear it, and there is no error, but yours will, so you can check out your implementation of the **getRange** method, how to get the page range, there must be a problem in it, it should only get the range of text, not the whole page range.

```vb
Function deletePage()
    Dim context As Selection, ur As UndoRecord
    Dim pageRange As Range
    Set context = Selection
    Set ur = Word.Application.UndoRecord
    
    ur.StartCustomRecord "deletePage"
    
  'return Word.run(async (context) => {
'    let range = context.document.getSelection();
'    let pageRange = range.parentBody.getRange();
    Set pageRange = GetPageRange(context.Range)
    
    Rem I have tested, if your **getRange** is well written, like my **GetPageRange** function here,
        'can get the correct page range in a document, not just the text range in it, then the execution of *"pageRange.Delete"*
        ' will be error-free. In the page after adding the chart and table, I use my VBA to clear it, and there is no error,
        ' but yours will, so you can check out your implementation of the **getRange** method, how to get the page range,
        ' there must be a problem in it, it should only get the range of text, not the whole page range.
    
'    Dim sps As Word.Shapes, ilsps As Word.InlineShape, tb As Word.Table
    Dim cln As Object, e
    Set cln = pageRange.ShapeRange
    For Each e In cln
        e.Delete
    Next
    Set cln = pageRange.InlineShapes
    For Each e In cln
        e.Delete
    Next
    Set cln = pageRange.Tables
    For Each e In cln
        e.Delete
    Next
    
    Rem In this VBA code, I can run this line error-free without the above from Dim ... to the last Next's block
    pageRange.Delete
    
    'pageRange.delete();

    'await context.sync();

'  })
'  .catch(function (error) {
'    console.log(error);
'    if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
'      console.log("Debug info: " + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
'    }
'  });
'}

    ur.EndCustomRecord
    
End Function

Rem credit with YouChat:
Function GetPageRange(rng As Range) As Range
    Dim startPageRange As Long, s As Long
    Dim endPageRange As Long
    Dim pageRange As Range
    Dim pageNum As Long
    
    With rng
        s = .Start
        .SetRange .End, .End
        pageNum = .Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber)
        Do While pageNum = .Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber) And .End + 1 < .Document.Content.End
            .Move
        Loop
        endPageRange = .End
        rng.SetRange s, s
        pageNum = .Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber)
        Do While pageNum = .Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber) And .Start > 0
            .Move Count:=-1
        Loop
        startPageRange = .Start + 1
        Set pageRange = .Document.Range(startPageRange, endPageRange)
    End With
    
    'MsgBox "The current page range is " & startPageRange & "-" & endPageRange
    Set GetPageRange = pageRange
    
End Function
```